# Allow OpenConnect at Login Screen

Tags: network-manager, openconnect

I would like to allow the option to connect to OpenConnect at login screen on Ubuntu 18.04/20.04.

The method my work environment uses requires MFA so I don't want it to try to auto connect.
I just want to be able to access and login to OpenConnect (and wifi) from Network Manager at the login screen.

This will be particularly useful for first boot to allow connections to the corp network for new users